# Websphere Application EAR properties file

Tags: java, path, ear, properties-file

So here's the situation: I'm working on a Websphere Application project using Spring.

I have a jar that I need to use. That jar needs a properties file. I have this file. I can place that properties file in my project and run a main() and it works fine. When I try to run it from my application server, it looks in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_1\properties\ for the file, throwing a FileNotFoundException

The problem is that, due to administrativa, I can't touch the server, so I can't put that properties file there. I also do not have the source code for the jar, so I can't alter the path it uses.

Is there a way to configure Websphere to use the properties file in the EAR instead?

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell without looking at the code that loads the properties (maybe decompile it if you don't have sources). It is probably looking for properties in the classpath, so you could try to either:

- put that properties in the jar which needs it.
- create new jar with that properties and put that jar at the same level (e.g. ear, WEB-INF/lib) as the jar that requires it
- create shared library (via admin console) and assign it to your application